# How to use FORMAT function without making a new query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string

I'm building this small real estate website so I can train my PHP + MySQL knowledge.

I want to insert the price of a house which could be, for example, 3,500,000$. Now as it isn't possible to add a number in a row with multiple commas (whether using DECIMAL or FLOATS options), I've searched and found out that using FORMAT() was the best way to do it as the browser automatically filled the number with the adequate number of commas but how can I do this without making two queries?

I have the following code:

```
  $sql_all_houses = "SELECT * FROM houses";
  $get_all = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql_all_houses);
```

Is it possible to use the FORMAT() function in this same query or do I need to select every row in my database and make another statement utilizing the FORMAT() function just for my price row?

Comment: Tip: Don't insert the formatting in the database, store it as a format-neutral number like `3500000.00`. Do any and all formatting in client code *only* where it can account for a multitude of localization quirks. There's all kinds of [PHP code](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php) that can help with this. In MySQL your options are extremely limited.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Thank you on clearing some frameworks but I'm familiar with some of them and I have the number stored as a whole in my database, I want to make the formatting on my PHP file, where I'm making my queries and displaying them.

Comment: Sure, then use a function like the one I linked to there. You can format any value any way you want to if and when it comes to displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you have a numeric value in the database, that you want to display in a particular format when outputing it to your application.

In MySQL, you can indeed use `format()`, directly within your query:

```
select h.*, format(price, 0, 'en_us') as formatted_price from houses h;
```

This adds another column to the resultset, called `formatted_price`, that contains a string representation of the numeric price, with commas as thousands separators, and two decimal places (you can change `2` to `0` if you want no decimals at all).

You can also add the dollar sign if you like:

```
concat(format(price, 0, 'en_us'), '$')
```